# System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties object has been disposed

Tags: wcf

When I raise an exception in my WCF service. The built in WebErrorHandler exception handler itself fails trying to access OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties as it seems to have been disposed. The consequence is that the real error is masked, and I always get an HTML error output.

Why would my IncomingMessageProperties be disposed? The service returns a stream - not sure if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was creating a WebFaultException. Now I create a normal Exception and use IErrorHandler to serialize it correctly to the client.

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me when i try to acces OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties from another method, not the OperationContract method.

To access OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties
create an extencion method to OperationContext to acces the property

something like this:

```
public static string GetClientIP(this OperationContext context)
        {
            string ip = "";
            MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
            RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty =
              messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

            if (endpointProperty != null)
            {
                 ip = endpointProperty.Address;
            }

            return ip;
        }
```